# Can time series settings in Google Data Studio change depending on date format?

Tags: looker-studio

I have a table with column "date" in YYYY-MM-DD format HH:MM:SS:MMM (2015-01-27 11:22:03:742). I'm trying to make a time series with the dimension of month/year grouping, to display the total number of records by period.

Settings:
period dimension: date (type: date and time)
period: date (type: year and month)
metric: record count

My time graph doesn't display anything. Can someone help me identify what's going on?

formatDate is the column created with the expression:

`PARSE_DATETIME("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",REGEXP_EXTRACT( create_date,"(.*):[0-9]*"))`

Using the date in its standard format, as mentioned at the beginning of the question, the same happens.

**When entering dates (original and formatted), both appear with null values.**

Answer (score 1):

The milliseconds have to be separated by a `.` not a `:`. An option is to import your date a as string/text and add a calculated  field, which parse the string in Data Studio:

```
PARSE_DATETIME("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",REGEXP_EXTRACT( data_field,"(.*):[0-9]*"))
```

If the dates are several years in the past, please adjust the Default date range in your graph:
[image]

Comment: Do you suggest creating a new field in my table that matches this expression?

PARSE_DATETIME("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",REGEXP_EXTRACT( date,"(.*):[0-9]*"))

I tried this, keeping the above settings, but in this case using this new field as a dimension. The problem continues. Graphic does not show error, but does not show anything.

Comment: @Jhw_Trw You are right, a new field is needed; I clearified that in the answer. Could you test it in a table? Please upload a screen shot in your question.

Comment: I put the image, hope it helps you identify the problem. Thanks

Comment: @Jhw_Trw. Thank you for the image. A image of the table would be helpful. Your example of the date is the year 2015. Then you need to increase the date range.

Answer (score 0):

I leave the solution to my problem to the community.

The problem is in the date format. Failed to get Google Data Studio to receive a date with milliseconds. By removing the milliseconds it was possible to work with the dates normally, managing to apply the available functions.

Note: It may be a knowledge limitation, but none of the date formatting functions work if the datetime field contains milliseconds (FORMAT_DATETIME, PARSE_DATETIME,...)